# JSON.parse causes "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, parsing

I have:

```
<input type="hidden" id="notifications" value="@ViewBag.Notifications" />
```

When I put a breakpoint on this line and check the value, I see that the value is:

```
[{"id":"42647","isRead":0,"MessageType":3},{"id":"fsh3hg","isRead":0,"MessageType":2}]
```

I want to parse this value in JavaScript when the page loads, so I wrote:

```
var notifications = document.getElementById('notifications').value;
alert(notifications); // it prints undefined
alert(document.getElementById('notifications')); // it prints: Object HtmlSpanElement

var parsedNotifications;

if (notifications != '') {
    parsedNotifications = JSON.parse(notifications);
}
```

but I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u" on the following line:

```
parsedNotifications = JSON.parse(notifications);
```

Why does this error occur?

Comment: `undefined` is not valid JSON.  What's the generated source?

Comment: it's a list of a class..

Comment: The value is not being output correctly.  here is a fiddle with the value correct and it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/A5Kf7/

Comment: you are doing some mistake while parsing...this error mostly appears when we use json.parse with an undefined object...

Comment: did you try using $.parseJSON(notifications) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote:

```
alert(document.getElementById('notifications')); // it prints: Object HtmlSpanElement
```

In the comment, `HtmlSpanElement` is a clue that something's wrong. Apparently, your page has a `<span>` whose `id` is the **same** as that of your hidden `<input>`, so `document.getElementById` finds the wrong element,  and `value` returns `undefined` because a `<span>` doesn't have a value.

Change the `id` of the `<span>` to something other than "notifications", and your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

So we know that document.getElementById('notifications') is there, which means that the only problem is it can't find the input value.  Sometimes external libraries will block the input of hidden elements.  Strip your page of everything except for the the code you showed us, and then try adding in the other libraries you've included one-by-one till you find the problem.